# Ensure Cell is NOT BLANK

Tags: validation, google-sheets

By observation I believe that data validation is only triggered when some data is entered into a cell. Is this correct?

Is it possible to trigger a validation such as `NOT(ISBLANK(...))` if the cell is blank? eg: the data validation warning message.

What I want to do is give a validation error IF the cell IS BLANK.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By observation I believe that data validation is only triggered when some data is entered into a cell. Is this correct?

Yes, it's correct

> Is it possible to trigger a validation such as NOT(ISBLANK(...)) if the cell is blank? eg: the data validation warning message.
>
> What I want to do is give a validation error IF the cell IS BLANK.
>
> Is this possible?

No.